# spurious indent combining standalone, french, itemize and verbatim

Tags: indentation, itemize, verbatim, standalone, french

I have an indentation problem that I finally solved adding `\usepackage{enumitem}` but I can't understand the reasons why the problem happened in the first place and got solved using `enumitem`. I nailed it to the following MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
some text

\begin{itemize}
  \item an item
\end{itemize}

some more text

\begin{verbatim}
some verbatim
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

which renders as

[image: base rendered image with everything]

but I don't want any indentation on the `some text` line. Actually if I remove the french babel package, I get the desired output but as I'm writing in french, I would rather keep that :

[image: result without french]

Now if I remove the `itemize` part in the middle I also get the desired indentation on the first line but maybe that's because everything gets indented and the standalone is automatically cropped.

[image: result without itemize]

but I would rather keep that itemize, and when I remove the `verbatim` part, everything gets indented

[image: result without verbatim]

I'm therefore not really capable to predict what happens here. I tried removing indentation using `\noindent` or `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` without success. I finally managed to get the desired output by adding the package `enumitem`, but I can't really determine what happened.

[image: solution adding enumitem]

Comment: Add `\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}` right after ``babel`

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I however don't see a difference in the output.

Comment: and if you add `\section{title section}` right after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: the section title gets the same indentation as `some text` in the first image

Comment: however it seems like including the package enumitem solves the problem.

Comment: you absolutely want to use the standalone class? Even `\noindent`does not help. I had not noticed the standalone class in my first comment.

Comment: I'm generating automatic randomized exercises and solutions for students with a chat bot (teaching with confinement), and the resulting exercises are posted as images. That's the simplest solution I found.

Comment: varwidth changes the list definitions, french changes the list definitions. Be happy that the combination with enumitem solves your problem.